# Excel - VLOOKUP to create new table

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have a given table B1 to H9 and I'm trying to create the output in below image:

[image: Excel]
[Link2Image](https://i.imgur.com/sd6qXe6.png)

**Input:**

```
+-----------+-----------+------+---------+------------+--------+-----------------------------+
| ArticleID |   Link    | Year | Quarter | QuestionID | Answer |           Comment           |
+-----------+-----------+------+---------+------------+--------+-----------------------------+
| 001 AAYY  | link AAYY | 2015 | QII     |        110 |      1 | comment 1 for abc 2015 QII  |
| 001 AAYY  | link AAYY | 2015 | QII     |        120 |      0 | comment 2 for abc 2015 QII  |
| 001 AAYY  | link AAYY | 2015 | QII     |        210 |      9 | comment 3 for abc 2015 QII  |
| 001 AAYY  | link AAYY | 2015 | QIII    |        110 |      0 | comment 4 for abc 2015 QIII |
| 002 BBXX  | link BBXX | 2015 | QII     |        110 |      1 | comment 5 for def 2015 QII  |
| 002 BBXX  | link BBXX | 2015 | QII     |        120 |      1 | comment 6 for def 2015 QII  |
| 002 BBXX  | link BBXX | 2015 | QII     |        210 |      1 | comment 7 for def 2015 QII  |
| 002 BBXX  | link BBXX | 2015 | QIII    |        110 |      1 | comment 8 for def 2015 QII  |
+-----------+-----------+------+---------+------------+--------+-----------------------------+
```

QuestionID and Description are static in row 14, A and B.
So as a dynamic output I need everything between C12 to I17.

I tried without luck to do a VLOOKUP by creating a new ID-column by concatenating QuestionID-ArticleID-Year-Quarter.

Can you give me an example how this could be solved?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is correct, except that, instead of Article ID (which is your comparison value) add link column. Similar concatenation inside VLOOKUP will take care of the rest.

I prepared a sheet for your quick reference. Please follow the secure link. Thanks.

[File with updated formula:](http://www.filedropper.com/stackoverflow30867636answer)

Comment: thank you this looks promising. Is there a way to make the table dynamic in a way that if a new ArticleID is added those two columns are added to the table so that there is no manual input needed?

Comment: My advice, maintain the tables in two separate worksheets or at least in separate columns so that you can extend the formula in Vlookup without any manual edit (instead of $A1:$H9, you can then modify as A:H which take care any number of new additions).

Comment: I can't get the lookup to work so that it will check the QuestionID in Column A starting row 15. 
In fact I don't need to match the Link-column but the ArticleID.

Also how can I automatically put the ArticleID in row 14?

Maybe you can show another way of doing it.

Comment: Can you please provide specific details such as in which cell, what forumla You edited and to what? If you observe formula in cell C15, the VLOOKUP is based on the QuestionID (Say, A15, A16, A17). I'm clue less where it's broken. It would be nice if you can share the workbook.

Comment: Hello PravyNandas: Get the file from here: http://www.filedropper.com/articleidtest

I've added some remarks and changed the lookup because the Link column is not needed anymore and makes it more confusing.

Comment: with a few modification I was able to solve the problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Create an ID column that is Question ID & Link.  You can then use index and match (or VLookup) to look up any value you need.  For example, If your ID column is in column A, in D15 you could put `=INDEX($D$2:$D$9,MATCH(A11&"link AAYY",$A$2:$A$9,0))`